# Not able to run the selenium webdriver suite on the Unix env

Tags: unix, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to run the selenium tests (which is already running well on windows) using Unix, however with no luck. Could anyone please help me with how to configure the suite to make it run on the Unix..?

Also if running on the Unix, how do we see the results, since to my understanding browser may be hidden during the runtime.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: well firstly, you can't run your typical browser on "the unix".  Do you mean Linux?

Comment: Which UNIX? Which browser? What errors do you see?

Comment: Yes thats right. On the Linux machine, Firefox is installed and firefox is getting launched, however i would like to know, if i can see the runtime execution ? and also how will i be able to see the results ? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

As on linux/unix you will be unable to run selenium tests in UI  mode I recommend you to use the following tech stacK: 
1) use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/)   as project build manager
2) use [Selenium Ghost Driver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver)  - Remote WebDriver that uses PhantomJS as back-end

The setup for linux/unix (that is actually working for me fine on linux):

`POM.xml` (file containing dependencies) :

```
.....


                 <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                     <version>2.41.0</version>
                 </dependency>

                 <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                     <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
                     <version>2.41.0</version>
                 </dependency>


        <!--substituting   phanbedder  with local Phanbedder implementation-->
                     <dependency>
                 <groupId>net.anthavio</groupId>
                 <artifactId>phanbedder-1.9.7</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0.0</version>
             </dependency>



             <dependency>
                 <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
                 <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
                 <version>1.1.0</version>
             </dependency>



.....
```

also an important NOTE: 
1) e.g. on linux there will be  a [selenium server](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) UP and running as a hub role
2) and on the same machine either on another machine selenium node connected to hub is also supposed   to be up and running.  On this machine   phantomjs is also expected to be extracted

launch hub:

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub
```

launch node:

```
phantomjs  --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444
```

**code sample from my project:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import net.anthavio.phanbedder.Phanbedder;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by dell on 03.06.2014.
 */
public class BrowserOneInstance extends BaseMethodsForMultipleBrowsers {
    private WebDriver driver;

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BrowserOneInstance.class);
    public static LoginPage loginPage;
    public static FacebookUserPage homePage;

    FileOperations fileManipulator = new FileOperations();



//  hub - nodes model (on local WIN machine) over GhostDriver- pHantomJS

    @BeforeClass
    public void seleniumGrridUponGhostDriver() throws MalformedURLException {


// either using Phanbedder  - CROSS platfrom solution 
//        File phantomjs = Phanbedder.unpack(); //Phanbedder to the rescue!

// OR point path to phantomJs explicitly
        File phantomjs = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+File.separator+"phantomjs-1.9.7");


        DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dcaps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);


        dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());

// !!!!! hardCoded initizliations of GhostDriver node
//        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:8080"), dcaps);

//    driver initialization   using  method  providing IP of running Ghost node connected to running hub
//        this.driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://"+getGhostNodesIp()+":8080"),dcaps);

//        node  connected to linux hub:
        this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://162.243.175.134:8080"), dcaps);


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //page instances init()
        loginPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
        homePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FacebookUserPage.class);
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If configured your project using Maven, then you are using "maven standard directory layout" and Maven could execute your build+tests  regardless of what platform you are on.